# creating visualization in Python : EmptyDataError

Tags: python, csv, visualization

I use python to read a csv file and create some figures:

```
import csv
Teaching=open('A.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(Teaching)
#type is list.....
#create figure1,2,3 by using bokeh
#.....
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(Teaching)
#create figure4 by using bokeh
#I use series type to create a scatter plot
```

It has an error: EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

```
EmptyDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-c97e3d2be637> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(Teaching)
```

If I reopen the CSV file, it will work and create a scatter plot

Please tell me why, how to modify?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you iterate the `file` object, you read to the end of the file, next time you want to read the data, it will return this error:

```
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

So you can try to reopen it or use `file.seek(0)` to reposition to the start of the file.

The code should be like this:

```
import csv
Teaching=open('a.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(Teaching)
for r in reader:
    print(r)

import pandas as pd
Teaching.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(Teaching)
print(df)
```